# How can i merge two nested javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, merge

I am currently using the code below:

```
function mergeFaculty(json){
    tempList = $.extend(tempList, json);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tempList));
}
```

However, it does not work.

the objects are the following:

```
{"modulos":{"id":"1","name":" Usuarios","paginas":{"id":"1","name":" Listado Usuarios","facultades":{"id":"1","name":" ver"}}}}

{"modulos":{"id":"1","name":" Usuarios","paginas":{"id":"1","name":" Listado Usuarios","facultades":{"id":"2","name":" editar"}}}}
```

any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: What should the result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think that you have a problem with your object structure, since your `facultades` key is an object and not an array. You should use an array if you wish to hold both `facultades` objects after the extension.

That said, it seems `$.extend` even overrides arrays, meaning it will choose the array of the latest object passed as an argument to this function. So this isn't good for you, as the array will still hold one of the 2 objects in `facultades`.

To correctly merge arrays we could use the `$.merge` function, but that is only good for arrays. Since you have a JSON object in hand this won't work.

As a result, what I did was simply write my own recursive code to utilize both features: a deep copy extend function and a merge function in case of an array.

Hope you find this useful to achieve what you wanted (explanations in comments):

```js
var tempList = {"modulos":{"id":"1","name":" Usuarios","paginas":{"id":"1","name":" Listado Usuarios","facultades":[{"id":"1","name":" ver"}]}}}
var secondObject = {"modulos":{"id":"1","name":" Usuarios","paginas":{"id":"1","name":" Listado Usuarios","facultades":[{"id":"2","name":" editar"}]}}}

// Deep extend recursive function
function deepExtend(firstObject, secondObject, tempObject) {
    tempObject = typeof tempObject === "undefined" ? {} : tempObject;

    // Flattens multidimensional arrays
    function flatten(array) {
        if (array.length) {
            return array.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
                return prev.concat(cur)
            })
        }
    }
    // Iterates over both object, extends and merges them
    function iterateObjects(object1, object2) {
        var keys = Object.keys(object1);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            var key = keys[i];
            var firstObjectValue = object1[key];
            var secondObjectValue = object2[key];

            if (firstObjectValue.constructor === Array) {
                tempObject[key] = []
                // Flatten arrays from each object
                flatten(firstObjectValue) ? tempObject[key].push(flatten(firstObjectValue)) : null;
                flatten(secondObjectValue) ? tempObject[key].push(flatten(secondObjectValue)) : null;

            } else if (firstObjectValue.constructor === Object) {
                tempObject[key] = deepExtend(firstObjectValue, secondObjectValue, {})
            } else {
                tempObject[key] = object2[key] || object1[key]
            }
        }
        return tempObject;
    }
    // Extend in both orders to find unique keys that appear only in one object
    tempObject = iterateObjects(firstObject, secondObject, tempObject);
    tempObject = iterateObjects(secondObject, firstObject, tempObject);

    return tempObject;
}


function mergeFaculty(json) {
    //tempList = $.merge(  tempList, json);
    tempList = deepExtend(tempList, json);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tempList));
}

mergeFaculty(secondObject);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your extend function to this: `$.extend(true, tempList, json);`, it should allow a deep merge

Comment: Link to doco ~ https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN

Comment: @Phil Yes, that the doc I used, thanks for adding it

Comment: Look like the faculty is overridden, not combined: https://jsfiddle.net/32haeup2/1/

Comment: Combined how? What is the "expected" way to combine? The question is vague in that regard. If the `facultades` is meant to become an array or something, then why not `paginas` become an array as well? What's the heuristic for combining vs overriding?

Comment: @Santi I don't understand, would you mind explaining?

Comment: I'm not OP. I'm merely saying that the return in your answer is identical to what OP's snippet *already* returns, so I can't imagine this is the solution that OP was looking for. That being said, I'd have to assume he's trying to combine them in one way or another, though that is for him or her to clarify.

Comment: @Joe I think he wants to add json to tempList, at least that's what extend does

Comment: I think we're all throwing stones down a well here until OP gives us an idea of what the desired result is.

Comment: @Santi His snippet wasn't allowing for a deep merge

Comment: @Santi Yes, you're right, I guess he'll tell us if my answer does what he wants

Comment: I understand what the parameter does, however in this instance it doesn't make a difference. Go into console and run [his snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/32haeup2/2/) and compare it to [your snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/32haeup2/1/). Are they not completely identical?

Comment: @Santi I'm afraid I'm using a cellphone right so I don't have access to the console. Do you know how I can use dev tools with an android device?

Comment: Not necessary, was just an example - the return of both is completely identical.

Comment: @Santi What does the result look like?